# How to get CPU usage?

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the cpu usage percentage to display in the label on a form?

Answer (score 21):

```
Import Namespace System.Diagnostics

' ...
Dim cpu as New PerformanceCounter()
With cpu
    .CategoryName = "Processor"
    .CounterName = "% Processor Time"
    .InstanceName = "_Total"
End With

' ...
myLabel.Text = cpu.NextValue()
```

Answer (score 4):

codekaizen said:

```
Import Namespace System.Diagnostics

Dim cpu as New PerformanceCounter()
With cpu
    .CategoryName = "Processor"
    .CounterName = "% Processor Time"
    .InstanceName = "_Total"
End With

myLabel.Text = cpu.NextValue()
```

In case you end up with "0" (probably because you just created the PerformanceCounter and then directly used it)
you need to add 2 lines as the PerformanceCounter need some time to work:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
myLabel.Text= cpu.NextValue
```

To Avoid that sleep you might want to declare the PerformanceCounter in your Class instead of your Sub/Function and set the probs in the forms loading event.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [How to get the CPU Usage C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-c)

Should be easy to translate to VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in .NET at least using the WMI API. WMI allows you to get a bunch of Windows Management type data such as CPU usage, hardare specs, etc.

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/WMI-Programming-with-Visual-BasicNET-What-is-the-WQL/