# How to Get Current CPU Usage Like Task Manager - Vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm working in a program that it needs to get the current CPU Usage How i can achieve that in vb.Net
i tried like 4 codes but i still get 0% every time . here is one example of what i've used [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796430/how-to-get-cpu-usage)

Thanks In Advance ,
Anes08

Comment: This question can easily be answered ... and has been answered numeri=ous times , mind to take a [look](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f56827c-b9ee-42f6-ab8a-19ddfb4b9767/how-can-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: this is C# i 'm looking for vb.net

Comment: It **Won't work** for me Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Why not take a look at my answer ?

Comment: The only reason the existing answer doesn't work is because it is actually `Imports` not `Import`

Comment: i got an open hardwar monitor it did all the job thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is not allowed to answer such questions,but still , here's something that might help you get started :

```
   Dim cpu as New System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter 
   cpu.CategoryName = "Processor"
   cpu.CounterName = "% Processor Time"
   cpu.InstanceName = "_Total"
   MessageBox(cpu.NextValue.ToString + "%")
```

If it doesn't work , here's a better version:

```
  Dim cpu as PerformanceCounter  '''Declare in class level

 'On form load(actually you need to initialize it first)

  cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")

  '''Finally,get the value :

  MsgBox(cpu.NextValue & "%") '''Use .ToString if required
```

Comment: i get 0 btw when i insert "%" it give a problem in build

Comment: @Anes08 They messed up, use & instead of + :)

Comment: @Jaxi , you are somewhat right , he could've gone with `+` if he used `.ToString` after `NewtValue` .. but who knew that he didn't knew lol :)

Comment: I tried like 4 codes and i get 0% in every code **Why?**

Comment: @Anes08 , recheck my answer :)

Comment: still 0% do you need to import something ?

Comment: Here is a picture 
i don't know if i'm allowed to post links 
https://i.imgur.com/LtF7MlO.png

Answer (score 2):

you can use `LblCpuUsage.text = CombinedAllCpuUsageOfEachThread.NextValue()` 
.There is a helper library to get that information:

> The Performance Data Helper (see Using the PDH Functions to Consume
>   Counter Data (Windows)[^])

.

Microsoft examples are in C but there are also corresponding VB (not .Net) functions:

> Performance Counters Functions for Visual Basic (Windows)[^]

Answer (score 0):

For me I wanted an average. There were a couple problems getting CPU utilization that seemed like there should be an easy package to solve but I didn't see one.

The first is of course that a value of 0 on the first request is useless. Since you already know that the first response is 0, why doesn't the function just take that into account and return the true .NextValue()?

The second problem is that an instantaneous reading may be wildly inaccurate when trying to make decisions on what resources your app may have available to it since it could be spiking, or between spikes.

My solution was to do a for loop that cycles through and gives you an average for the past few seconds. you can adjust the counter to make it shorter or longer (as long as it is more than 2).

```
public static float ProcessorUtilization;

public static float GetAverageCPU()
{
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        ProcessorUtilization += (cpuCounter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount);
    }
    // Remember the first value is 0, so we don't want to average that in.
    Console.Writeline(ProcessorUtilization / 10); 
    return ProcessorUtilization / 10;
}
```