# Measure a process CPU and RAM usage

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, cpu-usage

I've found various ways to track down CPU's and RAM's usage from *within* a process, in C#. I'd like to obtain those infos for an external program (like providing its PID).

Is there anything in the .NET framework that can help me?

Thanks

Comment: you mean, like passing a PID as argument?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-c
You can also use WMI( windows management instrumentation) for memeory usage . Check Win32_process class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx
Also you can go for performance counters (you code require admin privileges )
Look into WMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

Use [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx), and [add counters for specific processes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749266.aspx).

If you need to analyse the results, you can have them written to a [performance log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721865.aspx).

Comment: I need this for logging purposes, so I need to get the data in a format i can write, store and analyze.

Comment: You can save to a performance log from performance monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721865.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could host a PowerShell RunSpace and call stuff in there - it's got a lot more native stuff dealing with this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance into a System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter constructor - this should allow you to specify the process instance you want to monitor