# How can I get the Resource Monitor values in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, monitor, performancecounter

I need to get some of the values that are in the windows 7 resource monitor. In particular, the memory usage, cpu and bandwidth per process. I've looked into the PerformanceCounter class and I don't see a way to drill down to the process level. The resource monitor has exactly what I am looking for, and before you ask... I know this is re-inventing the wheel but the boss wants this. I looked into WMI as well and it seems most people recommend not using it.

So does anyone know how I can get at least those statistics at the process level using .net classes?

Comment: See
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411805/how-to-use-net-performancecounter-to-track-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-process][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411805/how-to-use-net-performancecounter-to-track-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-process

Comment: The links above are exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why I didn't see that when I searched. Thanks a lot man.