# how to get list of opened sockets from some process?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Windows Resource Monitor have a nice network filter and its easy to get network statistics of some process (TCP connections, port listen,  etc). I tried System.Diagnostics from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039923/how-can-i-get-the-resource-monitor-values-in-net) , but all examples are about CPU and Memory usage. I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box) project, but it looks dirty and unsafe. The only i need is to get Resource Monitor functionality in my c# project to do something like

```
var process = new Process("ProcessName");
var sockets = process.getSockets();
```

Is there any safe and legal solution without byte shifting and pointers?

Comment: **No.** *filler. filler. filler.*

Comment: **Yes.** _filler. filler. filler._

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, `netstat -a -n -o` will get you this information - including process id for each socket open or connected. Admin privs with -b option will even get you the EXE name. So if worse comes to worse, you could spawn a process to run netstat get this info.

Programatically, the Win32 APIs that will get you this information include [GetTcpTable2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetExtendedUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . You can p/invoke from iphlpapi.dll to call these functions from .net code.  See the [IP helper reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

You'll need to write additional code to map the "process name" string that your code has referenced to process id number. (Or the reverse).

Comment: Does this answer explain anything different than [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box) which is already known by OP?