# What is the Maximum Size that an Jagged Arrays can hold?

Tags: c#, memory-management

is the same as an array?
i have a Jagged Arrays like the next one:

```
double numbers[][]=numbers[a][]
```

where "a" can be any number. how can i find out the maximum size for the jagged array.

i have read that it has been limited by the amount of memory or virtual memory available but how can i calculate this if mi PC has a 8 GB in RAM memory.

my main goal is to find out how much memory my program is using but i have no idea how to began to find the amount of physical or virtual memory been used

Comment: I'd rather use performance counters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411805/using-performancecounter-to-track-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-process

Answer (score 2):

It's usually the wrong question.
And it's different when you run a 32 or 64 bits system.

In a 32 bits system you have a 2GB total limit (half of the available address space), under 64 bits it is virtually unlimited.

> main goal is to find out how much memory my program is using

That is different. You can start with `GC.GetTotalMemory();`

Comment: can you tell me where do you based your answer when you sayd that a 64 bit is unlimited

Comment: _virtually_ unlimited.  2G x 2G is probably a lot bigger than your HDD right now.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a single array (any standard array, such as `int[]`) is `System.Int32.MaxValue`. Which means your jagged array can hold `int.MaxValue` of `int.MaxValue` items.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-an-array-can-hold) from SO has a great answer regarding the max size of arrays.