# Saving profiler data from Unity with Android Gear VR (Samsung s6)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I've connected the Unity Profiler to the Samsung device and it displays the necessary data, which is great. However, due to the Unity Profiler only saving ~300 frames of history, this does not seem like an effective method of optimising scenes.

I investigated using Profiler scripting to record the logfile, which was fine when testing on my machine (Mac), although only shows the FPS, none of the other very useful data displayed in the Unity Profiler, eg: CPU/GPU usage.

I was wondering if there was a way that we could record and view subsets of the data sent from the Samsung s6 when testing Gear VR apps, such that the data is stored to my Mac and I could review each series of 300 frames and truly troubleshoot/optimise.

At the moment my solution is to find where i'm trying to optimise in the app, and blindly click "record" in the Unity Profiler so that it stops recording, I take the Gear VR off and review just the last 300 frames.

Any assistance with this matter is greatly appreciated, as trying to hit that 60-90fps milestone for the Gear VR is a challenge, and I feel I really need to be able to effectively capture the Unity Profiler information/statistics and find out what processes are being run.

Comment: Writing your own profiler API is the only thing left. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411805/using-performancecounter-to-track-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-process)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will investigate but might not be able to implement that in the workplace.