# Checking if the current user is active?

Tags: c#

Windows Live Messenger, Skype, the indexing service in Windows and the screensaver functionality in Windows all have a way of detecting when the user moves his/her mouse, or uses his/her keyboard to detect when they are active, and when they are not.

Is there a Windows API used for detecting if the user is present at his PC? What about proximity sensor APIs in Windows 8? Or is it required for me to actually detect if the user moves his mouse or uses the keyboard through existing Windows APIs?

Comment: @Christian.K might want to check your link.

Comment: @James Thanks. Now who would have thought that stackoverfow.com (without the l) also exists ;-) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244943/detecting-user-activity) is the correct link.

Comment: Christian, edit the original comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using this API.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo

It delivered exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to dig in to WIN32 API and Windows Messaging Queue.

In particular look at the WM_MOUSEMOVE message. Check; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616(VS.85).aspx

Use your application to review that message and build a timeout mechanism.

Also check out this link for a C++ variant: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11226/