# Winapi: Reliably detect user activity

Tags: winapi, user-input

I wrote a (very small) program that executes when a certain Bluetooth connection is lost. It should wait for a few seconds for user inactivity and when there is no activity the system should lock.

I do not require cross-session detection but it should be global within the session (i.e., not only input from the current process).

I would be happy if there would be a simple, yet reliable solution. In particular, I would like to avoid global hooks.

My first attempt was to use in the beginning:

```
LASTINPUTINFO lii;
lii.dwSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
GetLastInputInfo(&lii);
g_iLastActivity = lii.dwTime;
```

Then, I set up a timer and on WM_TIMER I do

```
LASTINPUTINFO lii;
lii.dwSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
GetLastInputInfo(&lii);
if(lii.dwTime > g_iLastActivity)
  LockWorkStation();
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to be reliable. Although I do not touch anything at all, the second call often provides a larger value.

My next attempt is raw input. When creating my main window I do:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01; 
Rid[0].usUsage = 0x02; 
Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
Rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
Rid[1].usUsagePage = 0x01; 
Rid[1].usUsage = 0x06; 
Rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
Rid[1].hwndTarget = hWnd;
if(RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 2, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE)
    return -1;
```

Again, I set a timer for my timeout and in WM_INPUT I have:

```
case WM_INPUT:
  KillTimer(hWnd, IDTIMER);
  // terminate my app
  break;
```

And in WM_TIMER:

```
WM_TIMER:
  if(wParam != IDTIMER) break;
  LockWorkStation();
  KillTimer(hWnd, IDTIMER);
  // terminate my app
  break;
```

Unfortunately this is not reliable either.
Also here, in some cases I receive WM_INPUT immideately although no user input occurs.
In other cases, I receive no WM_INPUT. It seems that this happens when my application does not have focus (i.e., it does not work globally).

I found some articles (e.g. [Detecting User Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244943/detecting-user-activity)) but ultimately they all point to GetLastInputInfo which does not seem to work reliable for me.

Are these approaches wrong? If yes, why? If no, what is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: I have always found `GetLastInputInfo` to be reliable. What type of variable is `g_iLastActivity` ?

Comment: Specifying `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` for `dwFlags` in the [RAWINPUTDEVICE structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645565.aspx) enables a caller to receive input even when the caller is not in the foreground. Since you weren't exactly specific on the details: What's unreliable about `GetLastInputInfo`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `RIDEV_INPUTSINK`. At a first glance this works! Regarding `GetLastInputInfo`: I wrote the pseudocode above. Although I do not touch anything (really!) the value returned by `GetLastInputInfo` increments. Hence, I cannot use `if(liiNow.dwTime > liiPrev.dwTime) { /* user activity */ }`. `g_iLastActivity` is a global variable of type "int". I just saw that it would better be `DWORD`. In any case, would `GetLastInputInfo` (assuming it works) or raw-input the more clean approach in the first place?

Comment: Pay attention to the `GetLastInputInfo()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302.aspx): "*The tick count when the last input event was received (see LASTINPUTINFO) is **not guaranteed to be incremental**. In some cases, **the value might be less than the tick count of a prior event**. For example, this can be caused by a timing gap between the raw input thread and the desktop thread or an event raised by SendInput, which supplies its own tick count.*"  So try testing the two tick counts for equality instead of greater/less than.

Comment: `if (lii.dwTime == g_iLastActivity) { ... Idle ... } else { g_iLastActivity = lii.dwTime; ... Keep waiting ... }`