# Windows performance counter doesn`t work - Committed Bytes to the Memory

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I want to check committed bytes. For that purpose Icreated `PerformanceCounter` . It doesn`t report anything

```
PerformanceCounter memComm = new PerformanceCounter("Memory",
            "Committed Bytes to the Memory");
```

Is there a problem how I create it?
Thanks

Comment: Please see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027341/c-sharp-get-used-memory-in

Comment: Running Perfmon.exe is a good way to see counter names.