# GET Process Cpu Usage In c

Tags: c, windows

How can i Get process Cpu usage in c??

I need Cpu usage of evrey process and threads.

please give me an example.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this in standard C. You need to use implementation specific libraries. Since you included the windows tag, do you mean that you want to use the windows API rather than "just C"?

Comment: You might be interested in [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It's possible I have alrady develope that, For answere i have a question, How many processor do you have on the computer ? and do you have linux or windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain C, this is not possible, but since the question is also tagged "Windows":

CPU usage is CPU time divided by real time. The [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions give you that information (among other features such as performance counters, which Joachim Pileborg mentioned above, but I think this one is probably easier).

You probably also want to use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first to know what processes and threads exist at all. You'll need to translate thread/process IDs to handles, but I guess that won't be a big hurdle (i.e. `OpenProcess`).

Answer (score 3):

In C, **total CPU usage** can be determined using [Performance Counters](http://en.literateprograms.org/CPU_usage_using_performance_counters_%28C,_Windows_2000%29) (there is a small typo in the example code: `sleep` has to be changed to `Sleep`).

In C++, C#, Delphi etc., I would recommend using [WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777661/returning-cpu-usage-in-wmi-using-c-sharp).

**== EDIT ==**

I found an approach to get the **per-process CPU usage**. For example, in order to get the CPU load of Microsoft Outlook, change the counter path in the above example to this:

```
PdhAddCounter(query, TEXT("\\Process(OUTLOOK)\\% Processor Time"), 0, &counter);
```

If you have multiple instances of the same executable running, you may use [indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also very useful.

Comment: The link to _performance counters_ appears dead, should it perhaps link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/collecting-performance-data instead?

Comment: the link has been dead. Archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20150307162536/http://en.literateprograms.org/CPU_usage_using_performance_counters_(C,_Windows_2000)