# How to find the cpu usage of a particular process at that moment of time in Windows

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, windows

Is it possible to know the CPU usage of a running/idle process programatically (in any language) in Windows?

Comment: Some what helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118647/get-process-cpu-usage-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care on support old Windows versions (earlier than Windows XP SP1) you could use [GetSystemTimes Win32 API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Otherwise you have to use [Performance Counters](http://en.literateprograms.org/CPU_usage_using_performance_counters_%28C,_Windows_2000%29).

Answer (score 2):

in `C#` you can do following:

```
private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

cpuCounter.NextValue(); // it will give you cpu usage
```

you should refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx) for details.