# How to profile memory and CPU usage from C#

Tags: c#, .net, process, profiling, instrumentation

I'm running a test that launches two processes, using C#. I need to get the top memory and CPU used by my process. How can I do it using managed code? (I also run it on Linux using Mono).

The architecture is the following: the process `test.exe` launches two processes: `A.exe` and `B.exe`. I need to measure max memory and CPU for processes A and B, from `test.exe`

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Top CPU used? Do you mean percent? When it's running, it is 100% of its core. When it is blocked, it is 0%. CPU usage percent by a process is a running average of those two. Is that really what you want to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to start the process. You can then check the `UserProcessorTime`, `TotalProcessorTime`, `PeakWorkingSet64` and other properties to check processor usage and memory usage. Check this [MSDN Article for System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't tell you processor usage, only CPU time.

Answer (score 3):

Try use this [Get CPU Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");


public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
        return cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}

public string getAvailableRAM(){
        return ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB";
}
```

**EDIT:**
So you can check difference before you start your process and after.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this

```
private ulong GetCPU(ThreadEntry[] thList) 
{ 
  ulong result = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < thList.Length; i++) 
  { 
    ulong NewThC = 0; 
    ulong NewThE = 0; 
    ulong NewThK = 0; 
    ulong NewThU = 0; 
    if(GetThreadTimes(thList[i].ThreadID, ref NewThC, ref NewThE, ref NewThK, ref NewThU)) 
      result = result + NewThK + NewThU; 
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); 
//often ERROR == 6 or ERROR == 18
  } 
  return result; 
} 

//GET ALL PROCESS CPU USAGE 
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
//reset results 
  this.textBox1.Text = string.Empty; 
//turn of timer 
  this.Enabled = false; 
  uint perm = GetCurrentPermissions();


  //SET PERMISION SO I CAN RECEIVE INFO ABOUT THREADS
  SetProcPermissions(0xFFFFFFFF);


//get all running process (OPENNETCF)       
  List<ProcessEntry> processList = new List<ProcessEntry>(ProcessEntry.GetProcesses()); 

//OLD Variables stored in list 
  if (OldResList == null || (OldResList != null && OldResList.Length !=   processList.Count)) 
    OldResList = new ulong[processList.Count]; 

//SORT by ID only for testing       
  processList.Sort(CompareProcessEntry); 
//GET ALL CPU USAGE       
  for(int i=0;i<processList.Count;i++) 
  { 
  //new value 
    ulong newRes = GetCPU( processList[i].GetThreads() ); 
  //result 
    ulong result = (newRes - OldResList[i]); 
  //valid result 
    result = result / (ulong)this.timer1.Interval; 
  //set result to the thexbox 
    this.textBox1.Text += processList[i].ExeFile + " " +  result.ToString() + " ;"; 
  //change old to new 
    OldResList[i] = newRes; 
  } 
  //sleep 
  Thread.Sleep(1000); 
  SetProcPermissions(0xFFFFFFFF);
  //start again 

  timer1.Enabled = true; 
  } 
  public static int CompareProcessEntry(ProcessEntry p1, ProcessEntry p2) 
  { 
   return p1.ProcessID.CompareTo(p2.ProcessID); 
  } 

  [DllImport("coredll")] 
  private static extern bool GetThreadTimes(uint p, ref ulong NewThC, ref ulong NewThE, ref ulong NewThK, ref ulong NewThU);
```