# Process statistics in c#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

For a given process, how can I learn its

- cpu usage (%)
- memory usage (allocated memory)
- network usage (bytes in/sec, bytes out/sec)

I'm interested in collecting this information from a c# app.

Comment: Can you not use perfmon?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help.  All the data is in the WMI database.  It is just how you access it.  For me, perfmon is the best tool and usually installed where you need it (like production environments). So, if you want a better answer, I suggest you give more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't use perfmon, because I need to collect this information programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters) and [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38438/Monitoring-Process-Statistics-in-C-WPF) + some c# coding skills are all you need.

Oh, and concerning the process network monitoring, [Microsof has a Network Monitor API](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/archive/2008/10/29/intro-to-the-network-monitor-api.aspx) but [YAPM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yaprocmon/) is a superman.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to track all that information with the [PerformanceCounter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).

You can find a more detailed list [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780836%28WS.10%29.aspx) as to what kind of information you can track.

Answer (score 0):

There are classes built into C# that can do this.  A Simple Google search "calculate memory usage C#" of "calculate cpu usage C#" brought them up

http://bhaskarrajukonduru-dotnet.blogspot.ca/2010/06/calculate-memory-and-cpu-usage-by-using.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c (note, you could of searched stackoverflow too)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads