# how to determine the entired memory been used by my aplication?

Tags: c#, memory-management

My application has 10 jagged arrays and 5 lists. Average ones are filled with different data for example double or string types. So I know my application has to consume a lot memory but how can I determine the total amount of memory being used?

I have read to use the `GC.GetTotalMemory` so the first thing I did was something like this:

```
var initialMemory = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
many line of code
...
..
var finalMemory = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
var consumption = finalMemory - initialMemory;
```

All the code is inside a function which `main()` calls his function, but the final result is zero. I saw that `finalMemory` is zero also, so first what is going on? the initial memory has a number but final has none.

Is `System.GC.GetTotalMemory` is the best option to find out the total of memory that is been used by my application?

Comment: The GC only knows about managed memory, which is only part of the memory used by your application.

Comment: You could do this with WMI google search using WMI to get Total Memory

Comment: For profiling I would highly recommend Red Gates memory profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Comment: Here is a Link you can look at as well.. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C

Comment: i was looking up for more information and foud how to get the physical memory,  the paged memory used and the virtual memory and i was wodering if this the intered memory that a application used or are there more?

Answer (score 1):

I once used:
In my global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WebConfigSettings.ShowMemoryUsage)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        logger.Debug(string.Format("Total memory: {0:###,###,###,##0} bytes", GC.GetTotalMemory(true)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, you don't need to collect before if you pass `true` to GetTotalMemory (the `true` argument implies a collect before returning).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64
```

This will give you the number you will see in places like Task Manager. However, this includes unmanaged overhead memory usage. `System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` will give you the actual amount of memory being used by the garbage collector (.net memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Link that you can utilize as well [How to do (Almost) Everything in WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-2-Proce)

Look at this StackOverFlow post as well.. there are many options WMI is very powerful
[How to Get CPU Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

If WMI is not what you are looking and or wanting to use.. then look at Performance Counter
here is an example of how to use them as well [Introduction to Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters)