# Restart IIS when processing power is 60% for 5 mins

Tags: iis, iis-6

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way to restart the IIS through a job or a service when the server's CPU processing power is 60% and it lasts for more than 5mins? If yes, how can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIS version 6 onwards you have Application Pools and they can be Recycled based on `Fixed Intervals` or `Memory Based Maximums`. Based on this I dont recommend you restart IIS based on CPU usage, you may litrally be masking a High-CPU problem. Get out DebugDiag and use the High-CPU rule and take a memory dump when the CPU is over 60%.

To answer your question:

Use this code below to monitor the CPU (taken from [How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c) - there are other examples in that thread that may be better suited to your usage, ie the one with Timer_Ticks):

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");


public string getCurrentCpuUsage(){
            return cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}

public string getAvailableRAM(){
            return ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB";
}
```

Then after the 5 minutes you can Reset IIS:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
//process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisreset.exe";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C iisreset /STOP";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Tip: you'll need admin rights to reset IIS.