# Get Available Free RAM Memory C#

Tags: c#, memory

Need perform free available memory every 1sec, so I use method and timer tick, but it is not changing, it shows always 8081MB in the label text.
So how to make it to it check every 1sec? Because using computer memory change also.
Here is my code:

```
    // Get Available Memory 
        public void getAvailableRAM()
        {
            ComputerInfo CI = new ComputerInfo();
            ulong mem = ulong.Parse(CI.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString());
            lbl_Avilable_Memory.Text = (mem / (1024 * 1024) + " MB").ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Get Available Memory Timer 

            ram_timer.Enabled = true;

            // end memory 

        }
        private void ram_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getAvailableRAM();
        }
```

Comment: You're getting the total physical memory installed in the machine not the free memory.

Comment: *available* memory is not the same as *TotalPhysicalMemory*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Try with this...**

Include a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
```

...and then update your label as follows:

```
lbl_Avilable_Memory.Text = new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory.ToString() + " bytes free";
```

...or...

```
lbl_Avilable_Memory.Text = (ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory / 1048576) + "mb free";
```

Notes:

1. Reference the `AvailablePhysicalMemory` property of the `ComputerInfo` class in preference over the `TotalPhysicalMemory` property you used previously.
2. The `getAvailableRAM()` method isn't required. Replace the call in `ram_timer_tick` with `lbl_Avilable_Memory.Text = (ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory / 1048576) + "mb free";`
3. It's also worth considering that methods that begin with the word `get` are expected to return a value. If the method was to stay then I'd recommend renaming it to `SetLbl_Avilable_Memory()` instead.
4. You have spelled the word `available` incorrectly in your label name.

Comment: Thanks you correct :) I dont know why I didnt saw that as well lol too long on my desk, need break. Thanks anyway

Comment: Must include assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, in order to see `ComputerInfo`.

Comment: `ComputerInfo` found in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` namespace

Comment: In the following post, the proposed answer suggest using the PerformanceCounter class, from the System.Diagnostics namespace(it also retrieves the cpu usage).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c