# How come my label isnt updating its content? WPF .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timer

Im currently messing around with a timer and a label and a performance counter because I am trying to make a label update its content to what ever the CPU usage is at the moment (and keeps updating at a certain interval)

But for some reason it just shows that my CPU usage is at 0% and its not updating.

What is causing this bug.

```
public void timerControl()
{

    DispatcherTimer dtClockTime = new DispatcherTimer();

    dtClockTime.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); //in Hour, Minutes, Second.
    dtClockTime.Tick += dtClockTime_Tick;
    dtClockTime.IsEnabled = true;
    dtClockTime.Start();

}

private void dtClockTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getCPUInfo();
}

public void getCPUInfo()
{

    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
    // Get Current Cpu Usage
    string currentCpuUsage =
    cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
    //Print it to the current label
    CPUUsage.Content = currentCpuUsage;
}
```

XAML

```
<Page x:Class="Hawk_PC.systemPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hawk_PC"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Background="#03a3d2"
      d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525"
      Title="systemPage">


    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label x:Name="osInfoLabel" Content="osInfoFriendlyName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-206,-76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="83" Margin="-258,94,0,-119" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Images/Logo.png"/>
        <Label x:Name="osInfo" Content="OS:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-234,-76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="ramInfo" Content="RAM:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-234,-50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="hddInfo" Content="HDD Storage:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-234,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="systemHealth" Content="System Diagnose:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-234,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="cpuInfo" Content="CPU:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-234,-24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="CPUUsage" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-190,-24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="startScanButton" Click="startScanButton_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Content="Start Diagnose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-258,55,0,-10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137" Height="31"/>


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: 1- Are you raising the event "property changed" in the setter of your properties ?
2- Is it really necessary to create a new object each time the timer is elapsed ?
3- Do you have a View Model ? are you using MVVM ?
4- Can you show us your view (Xaml code) ?

Comment: @NTinkicht He's not using binding, so INotifyPropertyChanged interface is not applicable.  He's setting the label's content in getCPUInfo().

Comment: Can you show us your Xaml code then please ?

Comment: John, where do you call timerControl() from?  Have you stepped through the code to see that the getCPUInfo code is actually executing and setting the label's content?

Comment: I'l add the XAML.
And yes it does set the label's content but it jsut sets it to 0.

Comment: @JohnM.Henreick I think I found the fix.  Check out my answer.  First part addresses your current approach and the second part presents a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the method you're using might need a second call to `NextValue()` and a pause between two calls to get it to work, based on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/06/02/how-to-read-performance-counters-ryan-byington/ and comments in this SO post: [How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

So, you'd modify your `getCPUInfo()` method to look something like this:

```
public void getCPUInfo()
{

    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
    // Get Current Cpu Usage
    cpuCounter.NextValue();
    // Sleep
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // Get Current Cpu Usage again
    string currentCpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
    //Print it to the current label
    CPUUsage.Content = currentCpuUsage;
}
```

Obviously, I hope that you understand that using `Thread.Sleep()` in a UI-centric program is a bad thing, so I'd use tasks and delays if you were to go with this approach (I just don't know how familiar you are with TPL, so I didn't want to bring in any further confusion).

Here's the demo of it working:

[image]

With that being said, you can solve everything by simply doing something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        DispatcherTimer dtClockTime;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeCpuPerformanceCounter();
            InitializeDispatcherTimer();
        }

        void InitializeDispatcherTimer()
        {
            dtClockTime = new DispatcherTimer();
            dtClockTime.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); //in Hour, Minutes, Second.
            dtClockTime.Tick += dtClockTime_Tick;
            dtClockTime.IsEnabled = true;
            dtClockTime.Start();
        }

        void InitializeCpuPerformanceCounter()
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
        }

        private void dtClockTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getCPUInfo();
        }

        public void getCPUInfo()
        {
            CPUUsage.Content = cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a demo:

[image]

It's working due to the fact that I am not instantiating a new performance counter on every tick and since the timer has a one second interval, that causes the needed delay between each `NextValue()` call.  I store both the `PerformanceCounter` and the `DispatcherTimer` as fields and initialize only once. So, this is a much better approach.

By the way, the XAML code for both tests is incredibly simple:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="CPUUsage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT:**

Per your request in the comments, here's something that would make use of `async` and `await` if you were to stay with the original approach.  This will prevent the UI from freezing up for one second every other second, as it would do with the `Thread.Sleep()` version:

```
public async Task getCPUInfo()
{
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
    // Get Current Cpu Usage
    cpuCounter.NextValue();
    // Delay
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // Get Current Cpu Usage again
    string currentCpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
    //Print it to the current label
    CPUUsage.Content = currentCpuUsage;
}
```

You may find more information on TPL on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Additionally, I can't recommend Stephen Cleary's blog enough.  It's a gem.  Here's an article on `async` and `await`:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

He has a lot of other articles as well and his book is top notch (although, if you can't afford it, all the content in that book is throughout his blog -- he's a good guy).

Comment: @JohnM.Henreick Glad I could help.

Comment: Wow your answer is amazing and very helpful!
And I am not very familiar with TPL. Might need to check into that because I've heard that Thread.Sleep() can be bad for the application due to a high ammount of CPU usage and other things.

Would you mind giving me an example of TPL or a good source of information? 
And again thanks a bunch!

Comment: And would threading be a good solution to this? Because it freezes the application in between intervals, was thinking that I might be able to create a thread that goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: @JohnM.Henreick Take a look at my edit towards the bottom of my answer.  I've provided a solution that will avoid freez-ups and put you onto a path to learn TPL.  However, like I said, my modified approach doesn't require any delay and double calls to the counter to get the value (and is actually a better practice, since you're not creating a new counter every two seconds).

Comment: Oh alright! Again thanks for the amazing information!
Stack Overflow Member Of The Year!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code in getCPUInfo() method with the below code,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void getCPUInfo()
    {
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
        // Get Current Cpu Usage

        cpuCounter.NextValue(); // Added
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Added
        // now matches task manager reading 
        float secondValue = cpuCounter.NextValue(); // Added

        string currentCpuUsage = secondValue + "%";
        //Print it to the current label
        CPUUsage.Content = currentCpuUsage;
    }
```

And hope your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Considering `NextValue()` returns a float, why would you use `dynamic`?  What's more, why would you even try to capture the first value in `firstValue` if you're never going to use it.

Comment: @B.K. Yes, you are not required to capture firstvalue and yes, of course if you know the value will be a float then dynamic does not matters.

I have given a generic code base. But I am changing it now.