# Unity3d development, how can I know how much memory of system is unused?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management

I want to know this to debug my app. I deeply suspect it's the lack of memory that caused the app crashed.
Thanks!

Comment: Post the crash log and we'll have a look what caused the crash.  At the moment you are grasping at straws.

Comment: You can use xcode, AndroidStudio or Visual Studio based on platform. This will return accurate memory usage as opposed to Profiler which provides Editor usage.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html).
Here, the section dedicated to [memory](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html).

An extracted from the documentation (Simple mode):

[image]

> The Simple view shows a simple overview how memory is used throughout
>   Unity in real-time on a per-frame basis. Unity reserves memory pools
>   for allocations in order to avoid asking the operating system for
>   memory too often. This is displayed as a reserved amount, and how much
>   is used.
>
> The areas covered by this are:
>
> - **Unity** The amount of memory tracked by allocations in native Unity code
> - **Mono** The total heap size and used heap size used by managed code. This memory is garbage-collected
> - **GfxDriver** The estimated amount of memory the driver is using on Textures, render targets, Shaders and Mesh data.
> - **FMOD** The Audio driver’s estimated memory usage
> - **Profiler** Memory used for the Profiler data

Comment: Thanks very much! But actually I want to know the unused memory of the whole system, or the mobile phone, instead of the memory about this application. So do I have some ways to know that(how to code in Unity3d)?:)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I've never accessed it through code. A suggestion, try to look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c. It's a post related to PerformanceCounter, available on C#. Maybe you could find it useful, I think you can use it on Unity too. Hope this helps ;)