# get CPU and ram usage of background worker

Tags: c#

i have a program that have two background worker.
i need to get how much `CPU and ram used per background worker`.
I know I can get CPU usage with this code:

[How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)
but i need get it per background worker. is that possible? how?

Comment: You mean you want to know how much CPU /RAM each task run by the backgroundworker takes?

Comment: @rene Yes that right.