# PerformanceCounter Datas not correct?

Tags: c#

i have a question... I get the actual CPU&Ram usage from PerfomanceCounter, but the result in RAM/CPU looks very different in task manager, why?

left taskmanager, right form1
[image]

thats my code for cpu&ram usage for my Form1..

```
    private PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);

    private String getCpuUsagePercent()
    {
        string abc = Convert.ToString(theCPUCounter.NextValue().ToString("##0.##"));
        return abc + " %";
    }
    private String getramusage()
    {
        return theMemCounter.NextValue() + " MB";
    }
```

my timer ticks in 500ms:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double ram = theMemCounter.NextValue();
        double cpu = theCPUCounter.NextValue();
        double cpucalc = ram / 1024 / 1024;
        string cpucalc1 = Convert.ToString(cpucalc.ToString("######0.###"));
        label37.Text = ("RAM: " + cpucalc1 + " MB; CPU: " + (cpu.ToString("###0.###")) + " %");
    }
```

//Working Stuff...

```
private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
```

Comment: You would use "Working Set - Private" to more closely match Task Manager

Comment: @AlexK. Short and Clear answer, works great with "Working Set - Private"! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are getting performance count of your current process

```
private PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
```

> Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName

so if you want to get the overall Usage
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

Comment: Thx, this is too helpful:)