# How to monitor CPU and RAM consuming by a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web API application in which I am working with the files security. I want to monitor the maximum and minimum RAM and CPU consumption for each task processing.

Is there any library to achieve this?

Comment: [How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)

Comment: [EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters)