How to get RAM and CPU usage percentages that match with values shown in Task Manager
I need to get the percentage of CPU and RAM usage at a given time using .net core 8 WEB API accurately with the figures shown in Task Manager.
The problem I'm facing is the percentages of the value I get for the CPU & RAM usage percentages are not accurate enough when I compare them with Task Manager percentage values.
RAM usage percentage values are close to accurate with values that are being shown in Task Manager.
Code I've tried:
public async Task<void> getCpuUsageData()
{
    try
    {
        var CpuThreadSleepTime = _appSettings.ThreadSleepTimeForCPU; // CpuThreadSleepTime - 30000
        var RamThreadSleepTime = _appSettings.ThreadSleepTimeForRAM; // RamThreadSleepTime - 30000
        var totalMemory = GetTotalPhysicalMemory();
        var totalCpu = GetTotalCpu();
        var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        var availableMemory = ramCounter.NextValue();
        var usedMemory = totalMemory - availableMemory;
        var usedMemoryPercentage = (usedMemory / totalMemory) * 100;
        var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        cpuCounter.NextValue();
        Thread.Sleep(CpuThreadSleepTime);
        var cpuUsagePercentage = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        var usedCpu = totalCpu - cpuUsagePercentage;
        var usedCpuPercentage = (usedCpu / totalCpu) * 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Used Ram Percentage : " + usedMemoryPercentage);
        Console.WriteLine("Used CPU Percentage : " + usedCpuPercentage);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


public float GetTotalPhysicalMemory()
{
    try
    {
        float totalMemory = 0;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT TotalPhysicalMemory FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            totalMemory = Convert.ToSingle(mo["TotalPhysicalMemory"]) / (1024 * 1024); // Convert bytes to MB
        }
        return totalMemory;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public float GetTotalCpu()
{
    try
    {
        int totalCpu = 0;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT NumberOfLogicalProcessors FROM Win32_Processor");
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            totalCpu += Convert.ToInt32(mo["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"]);
        }
        return (float)totalCpu;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}

I need help in fetching value percentages accurate to the Task Manager-shown figures.

Hi, does this case help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c

According to your description, maybe we'd better to find a "windows task manager api" so that we could obtain the data directly, I searched for it but no luck, I only found something related to windows API which might not be a good opiton too.

Yes no luck CPU average still give values which are not accurate enough with the values shown in Task Manager

Thanks for your confirmation... I think we do need an API from windows task to get the accurate result.

@TinyWang in that case can this be a potential feature request?

I'm not sure about it... Because cloud service is becoming more and more popular. If this is related to Azure, I'm afraid it might be a potential feature. But Azure might already had similar feature in one for the dashboard, so that it doesn't require an API.
